# Act on Outlook mail item when opened for editing

Tags: vba, outlook

What I'd like to do is act on a message as soon as it is opened in an edit window.

As an example, if I forward or reply to a message, I'd like to automatically save a draft using VBA as soon as the message loads into the edit window, simulating hitting the **`"Save"`** button or the **`Ctrl-S`** combo.

Thanks for the help.

(I'm somewhat familiar with application events such as **`ItemSend`** for the purpose of automatically running vba code, but am still pretty much a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [NewInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841(v=office.15).aspx) of the Inspectors class which is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code or the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869361(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Inspector class which is fired when an inspector becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point to an example of how NewInspector would be used? As I said, I am a newbie :)

Comment: See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started.